# How do I get my USB to work in windows xp guest. Ubuntu 16.04 host

Tags: usb, virtualbox

I have installed guest additions and extension pack and service pack 3 and user name and tried to find USB under devices tab in virtual box. Nothing showing up on guest OS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your user account to the `vboxusers` group of your Ubuntu 16.04 installation.

To add your user to the `vboxusers` group, run the following command from a terminal:

```
sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers <username>
```

It is recommended after the command that you reboot your system, and after the reboot you should be able to add your USB devices to VirtualBox.

After you reboot, go to your main VirtualBox screen and select your VM and click Settings above:

[image]

**Perform this step before you start any VMs.**  Once in your settings, choose USB and select USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller, then on the right you can add the filter for your USB drives that you're going to use with the VM.  Your USB device has to be plugged in so you can add your USB filter.

*Use the second icon down on the right with the + on it to add your USB filter.*

[image]

*Before reboot:*

[image]

*After reboot:*

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Terrance. I have done both of the above. Still no usb in guest. I believe it is a driver issue. I have a 64 bit ubuntu host and a 32 bit windows XP guest OS. So I believe it can not communicate. I can't find the right driver for the usb for the guest OS.

Comment: @torahtom It shouldn't matter if your OS is 32bit or 64bit in the guest.  I updated my answer to reflect some more settings that need to be enabled in order for USB to work.

Comment: Thanks again for your valiant help. It is much appreciated. I have done everything 10 times of what you have suggested. I read everything to do in the virtual box instructions and I have done all that you have said a long time ago.

When I click on the filters nothing shows up. It is not recognizing anything on the guest OS. When I plug in a thumb drive to the USB port, it is recognized in the host immediately. I have clicked on the + sign many times and nothing is there. My settings are all exactly as you have recommended in all the screen shots. This is such a hassle.

Comment: If you want to call sometime and could help, my # is 808-378-4170, HST. I live in Kauai

Comment: definitely worked out of the solutions I've tried :)